# jitsi missing in apt

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04

Is there a special reason why the [jitsi messenger](https://jitsi.org/) is missing in 18.04 (and since 16.04) repositories?

It used to be in there with Ubuntu 14.04, but then was removed again. Are there issues with the software?

Comment: From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jitsi/+publishinghistory, you are right that `jitsi` is missing for the past few releases. According to the first result in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jitsi/+changelog, it looks like the devs haven't figured how to resolve this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jitsi/+bug/1366121, so `jitsi` is currently in `yakkety-proposed`. I am not sure if there is a special reason otherwise.

Comment: @edwinksl that, and the FTBFS blocked transition to libav11 according to that bug. Since it's back in 16.04, following https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=759835, you can post this as an answer